# ruby how to match a substring

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a text file like this

```
....（omission）
ec2-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com : ok=333

....

PLAY RECAP   *********************************************************************
ec2-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com : ok=16   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0   
ec2-456.compute-1.amazonaws.com : ok=11   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
ec2-766.compute-1.amazonaws.com : ok=40   changed=15   unreachable=0    failed=0   
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0  

...（omission）
ec2-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com : ok=1231
..
```

How to get the content between PLAY RECAP and localhost
and sort the host name like `ec2-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com` by it's follow value ok=?

output like this hash?

```
{"ec2-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com" => 16,"ec2-456.compute-1.amazonaws.com" => 11,"ec2-766.compute-1.amazonaws.com" => 40,}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://ideone.com/QgscNB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an input out of the whole file:

```
▶ input = input[/PLAY RECAP.*?^(.+?)^localhost/m, 1]
```

To hashify the result:

```
▶ input.scan(/(\S+) : ok=(\w+)/).to_h
#⇒ {
#  "ec2-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com" => "16",
#  "ec2-456.compute-1.amazonaws.com" => "11",
#  "ec2-766.compute-1.amazonaws.com" => "40"
# }
```

To sort by host name (thx Wiktor Stribiżew for the reminder.)

```
input.scan(/(\S+) : ok=(\w+)/)
     .to_h
     .sort_by { |k, _| k[/(?<=ec2-)\d+/].to_i }
```

To sort by `ok` value (whatever it means.)

```
input.scan(/(\S+) : ok=(\w+)/)
     .to_h
     .sort_by { |_, ok| ok.to_i }
```

Comment: Look, *and sort the host name like ec2-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com by it's follow value ok=* - your solution does not account for that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Indeed. Now it does.

Comment: sorry my mistake, the omission words could contain `ec2-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com : ok=333` like this string

Comment: Pls see an update.